# How Can I Fix Corruption In My TortoiseSVN Repository?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Last month we were working as normal with TortoiseSVN but we began to receive errors when trying to commit/update one or two specific folders that aren't commonly accessed or updated. There were a mix of "An attempt was made to set the file pointer before the beginning of the file." and "sqllite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database." errors. A cleanup did not fix them.

We believe the issue was caused by a disk failure at some point, but due to the issues only ever occurring with these few folders, we don't have backups going far enough back to really do anything about it. We have almost 1000 more commits since that point. After some research I believe the best way to proceed is to dump all valid revisions to a new repository, and put back in files from the bad revisions after the fact.

I have followed along with the advice from this link: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/10/06/svn-corruption-recovery/

Below are the command line svnadmin commands I have used. D:\SVN is the location of our repository.

**Check for bad revisions:**

```
svnadmin verify D:\SVN --keep-going
```

**Outputs the following errors:**

```
r33809: E140001: zlib <uncompress>: corupt data: Decompression of snvdiff data failed
r34866: E720131: Can't set position pointer in file D:\SVN\db\revs\34\34866': An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file.
r34892: E160004: Reading one svndiff window read beyond the end of the representation.
svnadmin: E205012: Failed to verify repository 'D:\SVN'
```

From what I have read I cannot use svndumpfilter to exclude these bad revisions, what I would need to do is skip the bad revision and the one following it entirely when outputting to the dump file. **Based on that, here are the dumps I have created:**

```
svnadmin dump D:\SVN -r 1:33800 > tortoisedump.txt
svnadmin dump D:\SVN -r 33801:33808 --incremental > tortoisedump33801-33808.txt

(Skipping 33809 and 33810)
svnadmin dump D:\SVN -r 33811:34808 --incremental > tortoisedump33811-34808.txt
svnadmin dump D:\SVN -r 34811:34865 --incremental > tortoisedump34811-34865.txt

(Skipping 34866 and 34867)
svnadmin dump D:\SVN -r 34868:34891 --incremental > tortoisedump34868-34891.txt

(Skipping 34892 and 34893)
svnadmin dump D:\SVN -r 34894:34997 --incremental > tortoisedump34894-34997.txt

(34998 showed as corrupt at one point, but not in my latest verify check. Excluded 34998 and 34999 for safety anyway)
svnadmin dump D:\SVN -r 35000:HEAD --incremental > tortoisedump35000-HEAD.txt
```

**Now I create a new repository, called SVN2020**

```
svnadmin create SVN2020
```

**Finally, I try to load my dumps into the new repository. These run with no problems:**

```
svnadmin load D:\SVN2020 < tortoisedump.txt 
svnadmin load D:\SVN2020 < tortoisedump33811-34808.txt
```

**However, this is where my issues start. When I run the following:**

```
svnadmin dump D:\SVN -r 33811:34808 > tortoisedump33811-34808.txt
```

**I get this error, where gp_CheckInventoryTransactions_sel.sql was just a new file added in this commit**

```
<<<Started new transaction, based on original revision 33811 
* editing path : trunk/Database/Company/Stored Procedures/gp_CheckInventoryTransactions_sel.sql 
...svnadmin: E160013: File not foundL transaction '33808-q35', path '/trunk/Database/Company/Stored Procedures/gp_CheckInventoryTransactions_sel.sql'
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to continue?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I just got the error

> reading one svndiff window read beyond the end of the representation

when updating the SVN directory using TortoiseSVN within windows file explorer.

I fixed it by:

- Find the corrup directory (last directory/file updated before the error).
- Using the SVN export, make a copy of the faulty directory (or secure a copy from elsewhere without the .svn folders).
- Using SVN commands, delete the faulty directory and commit changes.
- Copy backed up directory back to where it came from.
- Using SVN commands, add the directory into your SVN structure.
- Commit changes.

Done!

No idea what the error means though.